# Allowing user space file-system to (kind-of) keep more than maximum number of files open

Tags: c++, c++11, cache, file-system, container

The linked code below is meant to be used in a user space file-system (fuse). Given that multiple processes may have multiple files opened on the file-system, the files on the specific user space file-system will map each of these open files to an (encrypted) file on a regular file-system, attempting to keep all mapped files open at the same time might fail pretty soon if there are many processes accessing the file-system. Doing an `open->action->close` on each file-system operation as an alternative would potentially have a rather big overhead.

The below container is meant to allow keeping a large set of files open while possible, hopefully the ones that are most likely to get once again accessed soon, and temporary low-level closing the ones that have been inactive for a while.

Is the design any good, or am I making bad assumptions that would result in trashing behaviour in real life usage scenarios? And if the design is OK, any other feedback on the code would be greatly appreciated.

```
template <typename nodeType,size_t maxOpenFiles,size_t maxQueueSize>
class openfilecollection {
    nodeType mNull;
    uint64_t mLastHandle;  
    std::map<uint64_t, nodeType> mCollection; 
    std::map<uint64_t, size_t> mFullyOpen; 
    std::deque<uint64_t> mOpperQue;
    uint64_t  getFreeFhNumber() {
       while ((mLastHandle == 0) || (mCollection.count(mLastHandle))) {
         mLastHandle += 1;
       }
       return mLastHandle;
    }     
    void cleanupQueFront() {
        while ((mFullyOpen.count(mOpperQue.front()) == 0)|| 
               (mFullyOpen[mOpperQue.front()]>1)||
               (mOpperQue.size()>maxQueueSize)) {
            if (mFullyOpen.count(mOpperQue.front()) != 0) {
              mFullyOpen[mOpperQue.front()] -= 1; 
              if (mFullyOpen[mOpperQue.front()] == 0) { 
                  mCollection[mOpperQue.front()].lowLevelClose();
                  mFullyOpen.erase(mOpperQue.front());
              }
            }
            mOpperQue.pop_front();
        }
    }
    void tempCloseIfNeeded() {
        while (mFullyOpen.size() > maxOpenFiles) {
            uint64_t candidate = mOpperQue.front(); 
            mOpperQue.pop_front(); 
            if (mFullyOpen.count(candidate)) { 
              mFullyOpen[candidate] -= 1;  
              if (mFullyOpen[candidate] == 0) { 
                  mCollection[candidate].lowLevelClose();
                  mFullyOpen.erase(candidate);
              }
            }
        }
        this->cleanupQueFront();
    }
    openfilecollection(openfilecollection const &) = delete;
    openfilecollection &operator=(openfilecollection const &) = delete;
  public:
    openfilecollection():mNull(),mLastHandle(0){} 
    ~openfilecollection() { 
       for (std::map<uint64_t, size_t>::iteratori1=mFullyOpen.begin();  
              i1 != mFullyOpen.end(); 
              ++i1) {
           uint64_t fh = i1->first;
           mCollection[fh].lowLevelClose();
       }
    }
    class node_handle {
        openfilecollection<nodeType, maxOpenFiles, maxQueueSize> *mCol;
        uint64_t mFh;
       public:
        node_handle(openfilecollection<nodeType, maxOpenFiles,maxQueueSize> *col, 
                                       uint64_t fh):mCol(col),mFh(fh){}
        void close() {
           mCol->close(mFh);
        }
        ssize_t read(void *buf, size_t count,off_t offset) {
           return mCol->mCollection[mFh].read(buf,count);
        }
        ssize_t write(const void *buf, size_t count,off_t offset) {
           return mCol->mCollection[mFh].write(buf,count);
        }
        int chmod(mode_t mode) {
           return mCol->mCollection[mFh].chmod(mode);
        }
    };
    node_handle operator[](uint64_t fh) {
        if (mCollection.count(fh) == 0) { /
            return node_handle(*this,0);
        }
        if (mFullyOpen.count(fh)) { 
          if (fh != mOpperQue.back()) { 
            mFullyOpen[fh] += 1;  
            mOpperQue.push_back(fh);
          }
        } else { 
          mFullyOpen[fh] = 1; 
          mOpperQue.push_back(fh); 
          this->tempCloseIfNeeded(); 
          mCollection[fh].lowLevelOpen(); 
        }
        return node_handle(this,fh); 
    }
    template<typename ... Args>
    uint64_t open(Args&& ... args) {
        uint64_t fh=this->getFreeFhNumber(); 
        mCollection.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
                            std::forward_as_tuple(fh),
                            std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
        mFullyOpen[fh] = 1; 
        mOpperQue.push_back(fh); 
        this->tempCloseIfNeeded(); 
        mCollection[fh].lowLevelOpen(); 
        return fh; 
    }
    void close(uint64_t fh) {
        if (mFullyOpen.count(fh)) {
            mFullyOpen.erase(fh);
            mCollection[fh].lowLevelClose();
        }
        if (mCollection.count(fh)) {
          mCollection.erase(fh);
        }
        this->cleanupQueFront();
    }
};
```

Here is a [commented version of the above code](https://github.com/pibara/MinorFs2/blob/master/util/openfilecollection.hpp)

Answer (score 6):

From a once-over:

**Naming**

- You seem to use all kinds of conventions, all lowercase, sometimes you use an underscore, sometimes you use lowerCamelCase. Perhaps you should stick to the underscore_style.
- The name `mOpperQue` is unfortunate, perhaps `closing_candidates` ?
- Could be me, but `operator` seems unfortunate as well, the name does not at all give away that it will actually open the file.
- `tempCloseIfNeeded` is unfortunate, I am not sure which part is `temp`.  I would call it `force_close_files`.

**DRY**

- `cleanupQueFront` and `tempCloseIfNeeded` share enough code that you could either make it 1 function or extract the common code into a utility function.
- `node_handle operator[](uint64_t fh) {` and `uint64_t open(Args&& ... args) {` share the same code lines and comments, one more opportunity to merge or use a utility function.

**Philosophy**

- I would much rather have a library that says *Sorry, you can't have this open file*, than a library that "willy nilly" can close a file so that I have to keep checking whether my `node_handle` is still valid.
- <s>By only checking the front for handlers that might need to be closed, you can create artificial limit problems, closing files that don't need to be closed.</s>
- If you called `tempCloseIfNeeded` first and enforced `(mFullyOpen.size() > maxOpenFiles - 1 )` and then call `lowLevelOpen()`, then you would never violate `maxOpenFiles`.

Comment: Point taken on naming.As this is meant to be used by a user space filesystem,normaly operator[] would equate one file system operation on an open file. Thats why mOpperQue has its name,its a queue of historic file handle 'operations'.The operator[] will conceptually just retrieve an virtually open file,its goal is to abstract the fact that there are closed files in the container.Point taken on DRY, tnx.Could you elaborate on the n2 philosophy bullet? For me that is the most essential part.At the moment I'm closing the files that have been idle for the longest time. Is that a misguided policy?

Comment: I re-read your code, point 2 is not valid. Updating my question.